# Java cryptography object in file password

Tags: java, file, cryptography

i try to find the good way for the best technology/method for hidden password in a file, but without use external jar or library.

Actually i use one object that represent a list of user name and password. Convert my list in a xml (only in memory) and after that, i store in a file with AES.

Use only java 7, no external library.

Is a good/secure method?
If this operation is no good, is possible to create dynamically xml encrypted?

thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html

Comment: As long as you have the key somewhere in your application, the security of this approach is not very high. An attacker can reverse engineer the app to find out the key and then decrypt the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FileOutputStream wrapped in a CipherOutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really secure to save passwords encrypted with AES because:

1) Where do you store the key? If you store it in the server, if an attacker violates the server and finds the key, he will have complete acces to the users information.
2) Do you really need to know the users' passwords? In many application, for security reasons, it's better to keep only the hash of the password. The username can be stored in plaintext and you can also add a salt to the password to enforce it. You can do that with some algorithms offered by Java7 platform. In this way, even if someone enters your server, he can't use users login informations without breaking the hash function.

Here's an example that worked for me:

```
public byte[] getHash(String password, byte[] salt, String algorithm) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
       MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);//The String rapresents the alg you want to use: for example "SHA-1" or "SHA-256"
       digest.reset();
       digest.update(salt);
       return digest.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
 }
```

You can also look at this link for a more complete example: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, my final goal is to have a file with all password, but no master key stored.

Comment: Ok, but than, how do you use this file? Is it something like a backup?